# How to remove PHPUnit?

Tags: php

I globally installed PHPUnit 5.1 using the PHAR:

```
wget https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar
chmod +x phpunit.phar
sudo mv phpunit.phar /usr/local/bin/phpunit
```

Here's the message I get when I run `phpunit --version`:

> This version of PHPUnit requires PHP 5.6; using the latest version of
>   PHP is highly recommended.

I now realise PHPUnit 5.1 requires PHP 5.6 (14.04 has PHP up to 5.5.9 only). I'm using PHP 5.5.9 and don't want to upgrade to the next version.

How can I completely remove PHPUnit 5.1? My aim is to then use the old version of PHPUnit (4.8).

Ref: https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have moved (and renamed) only one file. For this reason

```
sudo rm -r /usr/local/bin/phpunit
```

Why `-r`? Because `/usr/local/bin/phpunit` could also be a folder.

Comment: wouldn't it be better `sudo rm /usr/local/bin/phpunit/*`

Comment: I'm not sure `/usr/local/bin/phpunit` is a directory?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, answer changed.

Comment: Now it's correct. Sorry.